AsyncTelebot message handler not working with a state
I have a problem with states in AsyncTeleBot. message handler not working with state, and i don't have any idea, whats going wrong. Code is below here
bot = AsyncTeleBot(token, state_storage=StateMemoryStorage())


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def startup(message: Message):
    text = 'Hi! Lets start!'
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text, reply_markup=main_keyboard())


@bot.message_handler(regexp='Mark')
async def marks_main(message):
    text = 'Choose option:'
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text, reply_markup=qa_main_keyboard())


@bot.message_handler(regexp='Add mark')
async def marks_action_handler(message):
    text = 'Type your mark'
    state = bot.current_states
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
    await state.set_state(user_id=message.from_user.id, state=QaState.add_mark,
                          chat_id=message.chat.id)


@bot.message_handler(state=QaState.add_mark)
async def add_mark_func(message):
    await QaDAO.add({'mark': message.text})
    text = 'Mark added!'
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text, reply_markup=qa_main_keyboard())

from telebot.asyncio_handler_backends import StatesGroup, State


class QaState(StatesGroup):
    add_mark = State()
    all_marks = State()

Last handler, add_mark_func, is not working. But the state is added at the same time (i check this in debbuger console), but handler does not catch state

You have to add custom filter
for asyncio telebot
from telebot import async_telebot, asyncio_filters
bot.add_custom_filter(asyncio_filters.StateFilter(bot))

or add this for sync telebot
from telebot import custom_filters
bot.add_custom_filter(custom_filters.StateFilter(bot))

And add this if you use state as parameter in handlers
for async telebot
from telebot.states.asyncio.middleware import StateMiddleware
bot.setup_middleware(StateMiddleware(bot))

or add this for sync telebot
from telebot.states.sync.middleware import StateMiddleware
bot.setup_middleware(StateMiddleware(bot))

For example you can look in this 2 examples from telebot's repository sync, asyncio

Please avoid the impression of asking questions instead of answering, even clarification questions for the purpose of then answering (because they belond into comments, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). Even rhetoric questions which are meant to answer, because they easily get misunderstood as non-answer questions. Please [edit] and try for [answer]. Also please reconsider your decision not to take the recommended [tour].

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
